# Reusing Columns in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to refactor some swing code. Currently there are two separate JTables, and each one has all the same columns, except the second one has an extra column. We have a lot of event listeners that are connected to each column in each table for various purposes.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
TableColumn column_1_name = new TableColumn();
TableColumn column_2_name = new TableColumn();
...

column_1_name.code_for_adding_listeners_etc()
column_2_name.code_for_adding_some_other_listeners_etc()
...

TableColumnModel model = new TableColumnModel()
model.add(column_1_name);
model.add...
...

TableModel tableModel = ...

JTable table = new JTable(tableModel, model);
```

By naming the columns above, I can set each one up how it needs to be set, and then create the JTables with those named columns. Its more DRY that way. However, that above way does not work! It should... according to the javadoc, but for whatever reason the table won't display.

Please, any advice and keeping swing DRY and utilizing encapsulation or why my method won't work... its making me crazy. The way it is now (not how it is above) each JTable, which is almost identical, requires a ton of repeating.

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the TableColumn objects are simply not meant to be shared between different tables, so you'll have to duplicate them anyways. (I'm to tired now for looking at the documentation, might do so tomorrow if needed.)

You can however, share the code which produces them: Put it in a method which either returns a new TableColumnModel, or receives an existing one and adds your X columns to it. Then you simply call this method twice.

Comment: @Ben B, and yet again you make a statement without posting your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment. I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ben: Seems you have misunderstood me. You should not reuse the same column for one or several tables, you should simply reuse the code which creates it.

Comment: (sorry, Paul) that's basically wrong: TableColumns can be freely shared across as many table/ColumnModels as you like. It might not be a user-pleasing idea, though (f.i. resizing a column naturally will have a visual effect in all tables it is contained in), depending on the exact requirements which the OP chose to not share...

Comment: @kleopatra: Okay, I would categorize "might have unintended side-effects like resizing in all the contained tables" as "should not reuse", too, even if it is possible to share them.

Comment: generally a good advice, except when the side-effect is intended :-) Which doesn't seem to be the case here. The point I wanted to make is that TableColumn and TableColumnModel in fact _are designed_ to be shareable